# jquery toggle in open state on mobile devices

Tags: jquery

i use the following jquery toggle for my website:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Toggles paragraphs display
    $(".toggle-btn").click(function(){
        $(".row-text-1").toggle("slow");
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Now i look for a solution which shows this toggle in open state on mobile devices.

Thanks

Comment: In my openion you can write media query

Comment: yeah i got it with:@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .row-text-1 {
 display:none;
 }
}

Comment: I think your `$(".row-text-1").toggle("slow");` should change to `$(".row-text-1").toggle();`.